# CSS :last-child overriding all

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

The css with :last-child is overriding all other.

```css
.service-teaser .item:first-child {                                     
    margin-left: 0px;                                               
    margin-right: 50px;
}                                                                       

.service-teaser .item:last-child {                                      
    margin-left: 50px;                                              
    margin-right: 0px;                                             
}
```

My html looks like is the following :

```
<div class="container service-teaser>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <a href="#" class="item"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <a href="#" class="item"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <a href="#" class="item"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now every element with the class "item" will be overriden by :last-child. Where is my problem? :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `.item` elements are wrapped in `div` elements. They are *always* both the `:first-child` **and** `:last-child` of those `div` elements. Instead you need to place those pseudo-class selectors on the `div` elements themselves:

```css
.service-teaser .row div:first-child .item { ... }
.service-teaser .row div:last-child .item { ... }
```

Comment: I think this is precisely what OP was looking for.

Comment: You mean `service-teaser .row div:first-child...` actually.

Answer (score 2):

Each `.item` is located within it's own `.col-md-4` element, so there is no way you can target them with `:first-child` or `:last-child`. `.item`s should either be within one container or you should target `.col-md-4` elements instead. For example:

```css
.service-teaser .col-md-4:first-child .item{ 
  margin-left: 0px;                                               
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.service-teaser .col-md-4:last-child .item{ 
  margin-left: 50px;                                              
  margin-right: 0px;  
}
```

Comment: Why did you edit it? `.service-teaser div.col-md-4:first-child` was also correct.

Comment: @Abhitalks: To be more specific – I guess it is superfluous in this situation.

Comment: Yes, but for the Op the specificity would make it easy to understand exactly how `nth-child` works! :) Especially when Op compares it with James' answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `.item` elements are the only, and therefore last children within their parent elements. 
To achieve what I think you are looking for you need:

```
.service-teaser .col-md-4 .item {                                      
    margin-left: 50px;                                              
    margin-right: 0px;                                             
}
```

This would not be an advised solution as you should try to stay away from using framework classes as part of your styling, but with some small updates to markup you could achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1):

This is because in the scope of `div.item`, each item is considered to be **both** the first and last child.

Do this instead:

```
.service-teaser .col-md-4:first-child .item {                                     
  margin-left: 0px;                                               
  margin-right: 50px;
}                                                                       

.service-teaser .col-md-4:last-child .item {                                      
  margin-left: 50px;                                              
  margin-right: 0px;                                             
}
```